# Excel VBA to Create SQL Table

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have found the following code which is supposed to create an SQL table within an SQl Database.

The database is specified in `dbpath` and the table to be created is in `tblname`.

However when I run this code I have a problem connecting to right SQL database.

For example if I specify `dbpath` as "WIN2k8\Test\ABC"  ie the machine name is WIN2k8, sql instance is Test database is ABC.

For some reason it keeps picking up the dbpath as where I have saved the Excel workbook then WIN2k8\test\abc.

Can somebody help?

```
Dim dbConnectStr As String  
Dim Catalog As Object  
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection  
Dim dbPath As String  
Dim tblName As String  

'Set database name in the Excel Sheet  
dbPath = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value 'Database Name  
tblName = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value 'Table Name  

dbConnectStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"  

'Create new database using name entered in Excel Cell ("B1")  
Set Catalog = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")  
Catalog.Create dbConnectStr  
Set Catalog = Nothing  

'Connect to database and insert a new table  
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection  
With cnt  
    .Open dbConnectStr  
    .Execute "CREATE TABLE tblName ([BankName] text(50) WITH Compression, " & _  
             "[RTNumber] text(9) WITH Compression, " & _  
             "[AccountNumber] text(10) WITH Compression, " & _  
             "[Address] text(150) WITH Compression, " & _  
             "[City] text(50) WITH Compression, " & _  
             "[ProvinceState] text(2) WITH Compression, " & _  
             "[Postal] text(6) WITH Compression, " & _  
             "[AccountAmount] decimal(6))"  
End With  
Set cnt = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jet.OLEDB provider is for MS Access.  Try using a SQL Server connection string if that is what you are trying to connect to.  You can find the different types of connections strings at http://www.connectionstrings.com/.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You could also try thy udl file trick described at the following location - You can also try to the udl file approach to get your connection string - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140076%28office.10%29.aspx